# How to setup django 1.8 to use jinja2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

So, now that django officially supports Jinja 2 as a templating engine, I hoped enabling it would be as simple as switching a line in config. But when I do that, jinja fails to find my templates.

My understanding is I could manually configure a list of directories for it to look for templates in, but I would like it to behave exactly like DTL behaves by default.
(ie. look in the /templates directory). Basically, my app is structured the way it is suggested in the official tutorial, and I would like to use jinja without changing anything else. Is it possible?

Here's how my setings.py file looks now:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

The error I get is `TemplateDoesNotExist at /`

and here is my directory structure:

```
mysite
    mysite
    myapp
        templates
            myapp  
                index.html
    manage.py
```

please note that I am hoping not to use any external modules.

**edit:** as requested, here's the code calling the template:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in your view where you are calling the template?

Comment: Se [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701631/how-to-use-jinja2-as-a-templating-engine-in-django-1-8/30715508#30715508), I think it helps with your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Jinja template folder for app dirs defaults to `jinja2` not the standard `templates` folder.

So try the following directory structure and Django will locate your Jinja templates:

```
mysite
    mysite
    myapp
        jinja2
            myapp  
                index.html
    manage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that render_to_response can not take a context_instance for jinja2 templates

https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1163

I believe, but I might be wrong, but I think jinja2 can't share the same directory as the django templates.
try

```
TEMPLATES = {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'jinja2'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Jinja2 template backend searches the `jinja2` folder in the app directories, instead of `templates`. This has the advantange of preventing DTL and Jinja2 templates from being confused, especially if you enable multiple templating engines in your project.

I would recommend sticking with the default behaviour, and renaming your `templates` directory to `jinja2`. However, if you must change it, you could create a custom backend, and set `app_dirname`.

```
from django.template.backends.jinja2 import Jinja2

class MyJinja2(jinja2):
    app_dirname = 'templates'
```

Then in your `TEMPLATES` setting, use `path.to.MyJinja2` instead of `django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2`.

Answer (score 0):

The Jinja template folder for app dirs defaults to jinja2 not the standard templates folder.

So try the following directory structure and Django will locate your Jinja templates:

mysite
    mysite
    myapp
        jinja2
            myapp
                index.html
    manage.py

And instead of:
     return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')
you should write:
     return render(request, 'index.html')