# TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm receiving this error each time I try to access a list within a Django template. I have checked the answers to similar questions, but the problem is usually a lack of `%` or some other character somewhere. As long as I can see, this is not the case:

Here I'm passing a dict containing a a list of item id as keys and list of URLs to images as a value for each id. I know I should integrate this into the item model, but since I'm still at development with SQLite3 I cannot store lists easily. And anyway I am intrigued by this problem. So:

```
<a href="{% url 'details_view' item_id=item.id %}"><img class="hover-image" src="{{ img_gallery[item.id][0] }}" alt="">

Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '['item.id'][0]' from 'img_gallery['item.id'][0]'
```

Also, yesterday I tried using bootstrap4 flex-grid to easily achieve 5 columns. Since I'm using pagination to retrieve 20 items, my idea was slicing the list of items (model) for each row, like:

```
{% for item in items[0:5] %}
```

And I also received the same error, even when this was the recommended aproach in related answers aboput slicing data passed with a view.

In both cases I cannot find the problem, and I think both are somehow related.

I'm using latest Django 1.11.6 with Python 3.5.2.

Comment: jinja2 != django templates; the two are related but Django does not use Jinja, the latter was originally inspired by the Django template syntax but is a separate project altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nice to know, I always thought it was 100% jinja2. Is that the source of the error? Is that wrong syntax for Django-templates?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Comment: You shouldn't add `get_item` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. The `templatetags` directory is in your `shop` app, which is presumably already in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused between Jinja2 syntax and the [Django template syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language). Jinja2 is a separate project, *inspired* by Django, but not used by Django itself.

In the Django template syntax, variables in `{{...}}` *always* use dot notation, `[...]` subscriptions are not supported. Out of the box, the language *does not support dictionary key lookups*.

You can [write a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/) to achieve this, like the following, [written by culebrón](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable):

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

then in the template:

```
{{ img_gallery|get_item:item.id|first }}
```

Alternatively, you could switch to using Jinja2 in your Django project, replacing the built-in template language: [How to use jinja2 as a templating engine in Django 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701631/how-to-use-jinja2-as-a-templating-engine-in-django-1-8)

Comment: I'm following the instructions in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/ but I'm still getting the error "No module named 'get_item'". I have updated the question to provide more data

Comment: @RomanRdgz: from the accept I presume you have managed to resolve it? It looked to me like you had a `__init__.py` spelling mistake. At any rate, it'd be a new question, the issue with the syntax is resolved.

Comment: @RomanRdgz: ah, I see the comment on the question; all you needed was to load the module in the template and be *part* of an already-registered app.