# Getting TemplateSyntaxError when trying to use Jinja's replace filter

Tags: python, django, filter, jinja2

Below is the snip of code I am using.

```
<ul class="article_list">
{%for article in articles %}

<li><a href="{{article.title|replace(' ','-')}}">{{article.title}}</a></li>

{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

This is the exception I get.

```
Invalid filter: 'replace'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Mathematics/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'replace'
```

My intention is to redirect user to http://127.0.0.1:8000/mathematics/how-to-use-replace-in-jinga
when they click on the article: How to use replace in jinga

Please help.

Comment: I found it in http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators, its under list of builtin filters

Comment: In the traceback you should be able to see a template engine field. Check what is the template-engine. Is is it jinja?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki can you give a keyword I could Ctrl-F the error?

Comment: search for engine or template or render like keywords in the traceback

Comment: there is not a single mention of jinga anywhere.

Comment: You should refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701631/how-to-use-jinja2-as-a-templating-engine-in-django-1-8?answertab=active#tab-top It will show you how to setup jinja as template engine. Problem is django is using its template engine and thus giving you the error

Comment: then how is that it works fine when I did <li>{{article.title}}</li>, and I face issues only when I introduced replace

Comment: Because `replace` is jimja's template filter and it is not available in django's default template engine. You can not use jinja's template filters from django's template engine you have to setup jinja as your template engine in your django app

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try.