# Bokeh 0.13 move from components to curdoc with django

Tags: django, bokeh

Here (https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2018/6/13/release-0-13-0/) it is mentioned that now we can use curdoc() instead of components.

I tried to move the following code

view.py:

```
script, div = components(PlotView().make_plot(), CDN)
context['plot_script'] = script
context['plot_div'] = div
```

template.html:

```
{% if plot_script %}
{{ plot_script|safe }}
{% endif %}

{% if plot_div %}
{{ plot_div|safe }}
{% endif %}
```

to the curdoc example provided in the link. But this line in the template file `{{ embed(roots.region) }}` doesn't make sense for django.

Comment: No, tjat is Jinja, a superset of Django templates.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so it only works with Jinja, not default django templates?

Comment: correct. Although you can of course either do the processing in the view, or write a custom template tag. But nevertheless, Django templates have been restricted deliberately to avoid such terrible anti-patterns like performing business logic in templates :) The restriction was by design, and circumventing it, is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this line in the template file `{{ embed(roots.region) }}` doesn't make sense for Django.

That's correct. Like the documentation specifies, this is Jinja. Before the codeblock, it says:

> Then, those roots can be referred to in your own **Jinja template** blocks like this:
>
> (...)

You have basically three options to let this work:

1. you can install Jinja as the template engine, like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715508/67579);
2. you can write a custom *Django template filter* (and then call it like `{{ roots.region|embed }}`; or
3. you can do - which is probably the most "*Djangonic*" way, do the processing in the view.